# Create a 24 bit bitmap file with a black background using Graphicsmagick

Tags: graphicsmagick

```
gm convert -size 800x480 xc:black -pointsize 120pt -fill white -gravity center -font Arial -draw "text 0,0 'Harry'" -type TrueColor -depth 24 BMP3:output3.bmp
```

This code will create a bitmap file output3.bmp. However it is an 8 bit file not 24 bit.
I am able to create the file in Windows paint. When I create it in paint this is what I get.

```
Image: 24Bit.bmp
  Format: BMP (Microsoft Windows bitmap image)
  Geometry: 800x480
  Class: DirectClass
  Type: bilevel
  Depth: 1 bits-per-pixel component
  Channel Depths:
    Gray:     1 bits
  Channel Statistics:
    Gray:
      Minimum:                     0.00 (0.0000)
      Maximum:                     0.00 (0.0000)
      Mean:                        0.00 (0.0000)
      Standard Deviation:          0.00 (0.0000)
  Filesize: 1.1Mi
  Interlace: No
  Orientation: Unknown
  Background Color: white
  Border Color: #DFDFDF
  Matte Color: #BDBDBD
  Page geometry: 800x480+0+0
  Compose: Over
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: Undefined
  Signature: 89b0739176878b3715148cddb439c7a44cce2af130ee745527e854c73d471ec3
  Tainted: False
```

How can I get this type in Garphicsmagick?

Comment: I don't understand your question. It's not clear what you actually want - you show a command that you say doesn't work but you don't show what it does. Then you say you can create something in MS-Paint but that's 1-bit. Why should I be interested in that? What do you actually want? And what do you actually get?

Comment: What I want is to know how to create a 24 bit .bmp file with the code I posted.

Comment: Why do you think the 1 bit per pixel MS-Paint file is 24-bit?

Comment: Your command generates a 24bpp BMP on my system with v1.3.35. Please show the output of `exiftool output3.bmp`